# Does transferring a file over a local network use up bandwidth?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, bandwidth

I have a Windows 10 Server right next to my home PC, I've setup FileZilla server, and I've connected to it using "localhost" from my machine. Both machines are connected to the same WiFi source. If I transfer, say, a 1GB file to the server, would it use up 1GB of bandwidth?  The reason I ask is because it needs WiFi to connect to the server. I've seen [Does transferring files over a local network use up internet bandwidth](https://superuser.com/questions/733029/does-transferring-files-over-a-local-network-use-up-internet-bandwidth), and it says

> "You can disconnect your Internet and should find that it still works
>   fine, unless there is some strange reason the server relies on the
>   Internet."

But when I disconnect my internet, I cant connect

Comment: is your wifi device owned by the ISP, and installed where the service enters your premises?

Comment: How exactly do you "disconnect" your internet? A) unplug phone plug from phone socket? B) unplug router power-plug from power socket? C) something else?

Comment: Yes it's owned by the ISP and yes it's install where the service enters my premises

Comment: ok, that blurrs the lines a bit. Its likely that your wifi stops working entirely when the device is disconnected. if you disabled the wifi on this device, and purchased a wifi Access Point to use instead, you could transfer files between hosts on the wifi LAN, without needing an internet connection at all.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no, not under normal circumstances.

No traffic destined for another host on the LAN should ever cross a router to enter another network. If it is, then you have a privacy/security concern.

There are only a handful of exceptions to this rule, like VPN connected entities that are elsewhere geographically. They are virtually on the LAN, but traffic to and from them does cross onto the Internet in order to reach the other parties physical location.

Because your Wifi AP is part of the ISP cable modem, it may not work correctly when the head office is inaccessible. If you were to use your own AP, then No, you would not need Internet connectivity at all, and would use no billable bandwidth.

Even without your own AP, your ISP is being shady with you if they try to count LAN-2-LAN wifi bandwidth as meter-able. if they do (and only they can answer that question, as it is not an engineering issue) then find another ISP.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not!  You have a Local Area Network (LAN), (Which has your Windows 10 server and your Home PC connected to it via WiFi).  To access the Internet, your traffic has to go through the Wide Area Network (WAN).  In your case, when you run an FTP session, the traffic remains on the LAN and does not cross the WAN boundaries.  So, if you disconnect from the WiFi, you will no longer be able to use Filezilla to transfer a file because you will no longer have LAN access from your Windows 10 Server to your Home PC.